Replace DLQ response of kafka
I'm trying to convert the error message from a lister to not send the msg to DLQ, but my return topic with some minimum information. How can I do that?
I have a listener method that uses @RetryableTopic that works fine, but I can only use the information when it sends to dlq. I don't want a dlq, but to send myself the information for another topic when it fails all the retries. Can someone help me?
 @RetryableTopic(
            attempts = 2,
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 2000L),
            sameIntervalTopicReuseStrategy = SameIntervalTopicReuseStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC,
            kafkaTemplate = "requestProducerTemplate",
            include = {RetryableException.class}
    )
    @KafkaListener(
            topics = "listener",
            groupId = "listener-group-id",
            containerFactory = "myListenerContainerFactory"
    )
    public void listener(MyObject request) throws RetryableException {
        throw new RetryableException("Retryable Failure");
    }
    // this is the method that I want to send back the response
    private void transformAndRespons(MyObject request) {
        myKafkaProducerService.sendError("Error: " + request.getId());
    }

